# The differences among the imperatives of verbs of motion

Tags: грамматика, выбор-слова

I would like to see contrasting examples of the imperatives of *to go*. What are the differences among these?

- ходи
- иди
- пойди

Comment: See https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/13286/ходил-сходил-пошёл and https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/4454/3680

Comment: Imperative "Ходи!" is used widely in the context of turn-based games like chess. It means "Make you move!" Ex. [Лошадью ходи](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWw_ViXG-XQ)

Answer (score 3):

**Ходи(те)** is primarily used in negative sentences: "Не ходите, дети, в Африку гулять!" **Иди, пойди** are only used in positive contexts.

**Пойди** is telling someone to run an errand, to go somewhere with a particular goal: Пойди на кухню, принеси воды. If it's a simple round trip, **сходи** is preferable: Сходи в магазин, купи молока.

**Иди** is more concerned with the process of moving: "Стой! Теперь иди." although nowadays colloquially it can mean the same as **пойди/сходи** and it sounds a bit rude: Иди в магазин и купи молока.

Comment: _"Не иди за мной"_ is pretty common, _иди_ can well be used with the negative particle.

Comment: Go away home is only иди домой, not пойди, сходи. But go for some purpose all three can be used.

Comment: **иди** in place of **пойди/сходи** besides sounding a bit rude has also patronizing aspect, which is at play when it's used for instance by a parent giving an instruction to their kid, but it works in any close relationship where there's hierarchy

Answer (score 2):

The version **ходи** is about a *continuous* (going to and fro) or *repeated* action, while the version **пойди** is a request to go somewhere **once** (maybe for doing something there), another version of it is *сходи* (=пойди и вернись).

Repeated action:

> **Ходи** весь этот месяц к врачу на уколы, и всё пройдёт.

Continuous action:

> На тренировке **ходи** по бревну, пока не устанешь.

Single action:

> **Пойди** в аптеку и принеси аспирин.